# How to add two buttons under one column Lightning Datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-datatable

Is there a way to have two buttons in one column using lightning Datatable?
Would like to join the "Delete" and "Edit" buttons under the "Action" column.

[image]

**Controller.js**

```
({
    fetchAccounts : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.mycolumns', [
            {label: 'Action', type: "button", typeAttributes: {
                label: 'Edit',
                name: 'Edit',
                title: 'Edit',
                disabled: false,
                value: 'edit',
                iconPosition: 'left'
            }},
            {label: 'Action', type: "button", typeAttributes: {
                label: 'Delete',
                name: 'Delete',
                title: 'Delete',
                disabled: false,
                value: 'delete',
                iconPosition: 'left'
            }},
            {label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'linkName', type: 'url', 
             typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, target: '_self'}}, //_blank
            {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email'},
            {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'},
            {label: 'Department', fieldName: 'Department', type: 'Text'},
            {label: 'Description', fieldName: 'Description', type: 'Text'},
            {label: 'Fax', fieldName: 'Fax', type: 'Text'},
            {label: 'Department', fieldName: 'Department', type: 'Text'},         
            {label: 'Languages', fieldName: 'Languages__c', type: 'Text'},
            /*  {type: "button", typeAttributes: {
            label: 'View',
            name: 'View',
                title: 'View',
                disabled: false,
                value: 'view',
                iconPosition: 'left'
            }}
            */
        ]);
        var action = component.get("c.fetchAccts");
        action.setParams({
            parentId : component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var records =response.getReturnValue();
                records.forEach(function(record){
                    record.linkName = '/'+record.Id;
                });               
                component.set("v.acctList", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }})
```

**List.cmp**

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <lightning:datatable data="{! v.acctList }" 
                         columns="{! v.mycolumns }" 
                         keyField="id"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="false"
                         onrowaction="{!c.viewRecord}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by joining button, its possible to show the actions under the dropdown. Look at the example with static or dynamic actions https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleDatatableStaticRowActions

Answer (score 1):

Using LWC base component (lightning-datatable), you can create custom data type in which you inject your custom component in any column(s).

You can create 2/more buttons in it and fire custom events with data and handle them in parent component.